# Scapy http layer not importing correctly

Tags: python, scapy

I'm using Scapy version 2.4.0, and I have this following problem:

```
NameError: global name 'HTTPRequest' is not defined
```

When I try to do this in the code:

```
if packet.haslayer(HTTPRequest):
```

Even though I'm using the wildcard import:

```
from scapy.all import *
```

And if I add:

```
from scapy.layers.http import *
```

I get

```
ImportError: No module named http
```

Can someone help me out here :\

Comment: It seems that `HTTPRequest` are HTTP 1.X requests which were not present in scapy 2.4.0 (see https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layers/http.html#http-2-x) . It seems that to send HTTP request with your scapy version you'll have to follow this tutorial: https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/master/doc/notebooks/HTTP_2_Tuto.ipynb

Comment: I installed scapy 2.4.4 via `pip` and I have that layer. Can you just update the library?